# Visual Studio 2022 giving an error when trying to run/discover nunit tests

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a small test project that was working perfectly fine. Test were discoverable and ran and worked. Stepped away from my computer for a bit and came back to the tests not being there and now can't be discovered. I'm getting this error in the output when building/rebuilding

`

```
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\InternalTrace.20560.log' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at NUnit.Engine.Internal.InternalTraceWriter..ctor(String logPath)
   at NUnit.Engine.Internal.InternalTrace.Initialize(String logName, InternalTraceLevel level)
   at NUnit.Engine.TestEngine.Initialize()
   at NUnit.Engine.TestEngine.GetRunner(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.NUnit3TestDiscoverer.DiscoverTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDiscoveryContext discoveryContext, IMessageLogger messageLogger, ITestCaseDiscoverySink discoverySink) in D:\repos\NUnit\nunit3-vs-adapter\src\NUnitTestAdapter\NUnit3TestDiscoverer.cs:line 82
NUnit Adapter 4.3.0.0: Test discovery complete
```

`

I've tried running as Admin and that works fine but the code is on my work laptop which doesn't have admin access. The issue im having is this WAS working so i don't understand what would have changed to make it all of a sudden stop.

Comment: Try rebooting? lol

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/files/9965427/NUnit3TestAdapter.4.3.1-alpha.111.zip

Comment: Tried the above and it worked! Looks like its a bug in the latest build of nunit3